# Why does EF Migrations insist on me enabling automatic migrations?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I am very, very new to using migrations, but based on the answer to the SO question [Database is not getting created at first time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25980435/database-is-not-getting-created-at-first-time), using the Powershell command `Update-Database -Script` should give me a script to execute outside of automatic migrations. Yet when I try running that command, I get an error message that says:

> Unable to update database to match the current model because there are
>   pending changes and automatic migration is disabled

I would rather follow Chris Pratt's sage advice - in his answer to the linked question - and leave automatic migrations disabled, but the alternative he offers is insisting on automatic migrations.

I am trying to create the database from scratch, using the `CreateDatabaseIfNotExists` initializer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means there are changes to your current model that haven't been added to a migration.

Try:

```
Add-Migration YourMigrationName
Update-Database -Script
```

This will first create a migration with the updated model changes, then you can generate the update database SQL script.